# Is it safe to delete unused Parse frameworks from an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, frameworks

I am making an iOS app that requires push notifications, and figured that Parse would be the simplest way to do what I wanted. Unfortunately though, when I went to the quick start guide on their website, the instructions say that I have to import all of the Parse libraries.

My question therefore is, since I only need `Parse.framework` and `Bolts.framework`, is it safe to delete the others such as `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` that are just consuming space?

I tried removing some of the unused ones from the **Link Binary with Libraries** stage and then building - which seems to work - but I’m not sure that this will remain the case when I submit the app.

**UPDATE**: So apparently, deleting the unused frameworks works just fine (at least it works on the device that I tested it on). Now it's just a matter of submitting the app and hoping that it works in the app store as well. If anybody has faced this problem before and has submitted their app, do let me know.

Comment: Let `git` help. Commit the working version.  Delete whatever you like.  Test.  If it fails discard the current changes and you are back where you started.

Comment: @trojanfoe nice idea, I'll try that. Is there any reason I should use git over snapshots though?

Comment: Yes.  `git` is a universally-accepted source control system.  Snapshots is a joke.

Comment: Git includes snapshots, what do you mean?

Comment: @trojanfoe I was just worried that there would be too many commits then, but I'll use git in that case.

Comment: Too many commits is not something to worry about.

Comment: @Zimano I was talking about the built-in Xcode snapshots feature

Comment: Ooh alright! Hope to see if it worked!

Comment: @Zimano I'll be sure to let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: So apparently, deleting the unused frameworks works just fine (at least it works on the device that I tested it on). Now it's just a matter of submitting the app and hoping that it works in the app store as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using CocoaPods to manage your dependencies so you don't have to worry about these kinds of things.

If you've never used it before take a look at [their website.](https://cocoapods.org) Its very straightforward and makes it easy to install dependencies.

All you would need in your podfile for Parse is 'pod 'Parse''

Comment: I had actually tried to use CocoaPods earlier, but ran into a bunch of linker errors when trying to compile. I'll look into it again though.

Comment: I can help you while you're setting it up if you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately its already midnight where I live, so I'll try figuring it out myself later. Thanks anyways :)